# django-apscheduler don't in django-admin

Tags: django

I install django-apscheduler ,an I acording to document registed in the view ,but it don't in the admin site,how can I get it?

```
import time

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from django_apscheduler.jobstores import DjangoJobStore, register_events, register_job

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")

@register_job(scheduler, "interval", seconds=1)
def test_job():
   time.sleep(4)
   print("I'm a test job!")
   # raise ValueError("Olala!")

   register_events(scheduler)

   scheduler.start()
   print("Scheduler started!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add it the package in the INSTALLED_APPS sections of your settings.py?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "django_apscheduler",
)
```